# Store strtok in an array ~ C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

I was given the `parseInput` function from a teacher. I am not able to get it to run without a segmentation fault and I hope you guys can help me.

I think it has to do with how I pass `total_cmd_words`, but I'm not sure.

```c
// Libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int parseInput(char *input, char* splitWords[]){
      int wordInd = 0;
      splitWords[0] = strtok(input, " "); // VSCODE says this line is causing the fault
      while(splitWords[wordInd] != NULL){
              splitWords[++wordInd] = strtok(NULL, " ");
      }

      return wordInd;
}

int main(){

  char* total_cmd = "file1 > file2";
  char* total_cmd_words[] = {};

  parseInput(total_cmd, total_cmd_words);

}
```

gdb gives this output:

```
__GI___strtok_r (s=0x555555556006 "file1 > file2", delim=0x555555556004 " ", 
    save_ptr=0x7ffff7fb0ca8 <olds>) at strtok_r.c:72
72  strtok_r.c: No such file or directory.
```

Changing:
`char* total_cmd_words[] = {};`
to this:
`char* total_cmd_words[100] = {};`
Still results in a segmentation fault.

Comment: 1) use sane loops 2) dont use `strtok()` 3 Profit!

Comment: `char* total_cmd_words[10] = {};` also results in a segmentation fault.

Comment: You're also blasting a string literal, which is read-only.

Comment: `char* total_cmd = "file1 > file2";` ===> `char total_cmd[] = "file1 > file2";` - as aI said before, you're blasting a read-only string literal. `strtok` modifies the input buffer by dropping terminators where it sees fit. You can't do that to a read-only string literals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two errors in your `main` function.

First, your declaration of `total_cmd_words` is wrong: as it stands, you're declaring an array of zero length – so there is no space to actually store the pointrs returned by the `strtok` function in your `parseInput` function. You need to specify a dimension for the array inside the `[]` – one that is large enough to hold the maximum number of values that your are likely to encounter.

Second, a call to `strtok` **modifies the string given as its first argument**. However, your `total_cmd` is a pointer to a **non-mutable** string literal. Instead, declare that as an *array* of `char` and initialize it with a *copy* of the string literal.

Here's a possible working version of your `main`:

```c
int main()
{
    char total_cmd[] = "file1 > file2";
    char* total_cmd_words[10] = {0,};
    int p = parseInput(total_cmd, total_cmd_words);
    printf("%d\n", p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declared

```c
char* total_cmd_words[] = {};
```

you didn't specify an array length.  Therefore, it's length was determined by your initializer which was empty.

So, when you do

```c
splitWords[0] = strtok(input, " ");
```

you're assigning to the first element of a 0-length array.  That's undefined behavior and the most likely cause of your segmentation fault.

Comment: This definition still results in a segmentation fault.
`char* total_cmd_words[100] = {};`

Comment: Are you familiar with use of any debugging tools such as valgrind?